# jQuery Mobile with my Contact Form

Tags: jquery, mobile

Can't get jquery mobile to work with my contact form.

Have validation using jquery.validate.js.  If I use this, the select menu does not work on mobile.

Also on Submit, it gives "error loading page".

These are the JS and CSS files being used in this order. Please help

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/about/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="/about/js/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
    <script src="/about/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mobile/mobile.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/mobile.css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"></link>
```

Here's my Form.

```
<form id="contact" action="/about/process" method="post">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="required" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" value="" id="name"></div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="phone">Phone:</label>
    <input type="text" class="required" name="phone" placeholder="678-555-1212" value="" id="phone"></div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" class="required email" name="email" placeholder="yourname@domain.com" value="" id="email"></div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="interestedIn">Interested In:</label>
        <select name="interestedIn" class="required" id="interestedIn">
        <option value="">Select One</option>
        <option value="Karate">Karate</option>
        <option value="Tai Chi">Tai Chi</option>
        <option value="Martial Arts">Martial Arts</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="button_text" value="Send"><br />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery validate doesn't work with select elements - or more realistically, it may sort-of work but not behave as you would expect, which I think is what you are experiencing.

Comment: If I remove the class="required" it still behaves the same, can't select and refresh.  If I remove the actual jquery.validate.js file, select then works.